# what is happening behind the scenes in optional if statements in swift

Tags: swift, option-type

accodring to apple documentation the following code checks if convertedNumber has been initialized, and if so, it executes the if block.

```
let convertedNumber: Int?

if convertedNumber {
//do stuff
}
```

I'm interested in what's happening behind the scenes. Is this some sort of shorthand notation, because the condition in if statement must evaluate to boolean true or false. how is the fact that convertedNumebr contains a value transformed into true or false?

I was thinking that this is a shorthand notation for:

```
if convertedNumber!=nil {
//do stuff
}
```

correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "shorthand test" for optionals

```
if someOptional {
//do stuff
}
```

existed only in early version of Swift.
From the Xcode 6 beta 5 release notes:

> Optionals no longer conform to the BooleanType (formerly LogicValue)
>   protocol, so they may no longer be used in place of boolean
>   expressions (they must be explicitly compared with v != nil). This
>   resolves confusion around Bool? and related types, makes code more
>   explicit about what test is expected, and is more consistent with the
>   rest of the language.

So with current Xcode versions, you have to test with

```
if someOptional != nil {
//do stuff
}
```

or, of course, with optional binding.

In addition, `struct Optional` conforms to the `NilLiteralConvertible`
protocol, so that (in this context) `nil` is identical to
`Optional<T>.None` with the matching type `T`.

Comment: damn... I've printed a verison uploaded in september. Did swift change a lot since then?

Comment: @krompir2: You must be kidding :) There were new Xcode releases about once a month. The documentation seems to be updated less frequently, you'll find the history here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/RevisionHistory.html